# Discord py Not Printing Specific JSON Information

Tags: python, discord

I'm attempting to make my Discord bot say the set prefix by the server.

Here is the code for the prefix changing command.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True) 
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}')
```

That isn't the problem, the problem is me trying to let me help command say the specific prefix that the user has set. I tried making it read the json and get the prefix from the guild's ID but this isn't working.

```
@client.command(aliases=["commands"])
async def help(ctx, cmd=None):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: 
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    p = prefixes[ctx.guild.id]
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0xff0080, description=
    f"<:polylogo:894531390899642419> **Prefix** ``{p}``\nJoin our [Official Discord](https://discord.com)\n\n**Moderation (7)** \n``{p}Warn, {p}Warnings, {p}Mute, {p}Unmute, {p}Kick, {p}Ban, {p}Unban``\n\n**Utility / Miscellaneous (5)** \n ``{p}Ping, {p}Avatar, {p}Info, {p}Sinfo, {p}Help, {p}Members``")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following line:

```py
p = prefixes[ctx.guild.id]
```

You will always get a `KeyError`, because of the way you store the ID and then request it. Storing it as a `str` and requesting it in that way will never work.

Simply change this line to the following:

```py
p = prefixes[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]
```

I would also recommend to work with a `try/except` statement, as some guilds may not have set a prefix, and you will then get an error if they try to run the command.

**A possible new code could be:**

```py
@client.command(aliases=["commands"])
async def help(ctx):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        custom_prefixes = json.load(fp) # Open and load the JSON
    try: # Try to
        p = custom_prefixes[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] # Get the custom prefix
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0080,
                              description=
                              f"**Prefix** ``{p}``\n\n**Moderation (7)** \n``{p}Warn, {p}Warnings, {p}Mute, [SHORTENED]")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed) # Send the embed
    except:
        await ctx.send("All my commands:") # If no prefix was found
```